# calculate day appearance over time

Tags: php

I want to calculate the times a day has appeared between 2 dates.

for example: 
I want to calculate the times that "Saturday" has appeared from 05/09/2013 until today (19/03/2014). The right answer is 28.

Any idea how I can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
$old_date = "2014-01-22";
$new_date = "2014-02-20";

$diff = strtotime($new_date) - strtotime($old_date);

echo floor($diff/(60*60*24));
```

Comment: I think, if the day count between two days are smaller then 7, (like 4), some one can never be sure that if there is a Monday between those dates or not with a pure mathematical function.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that there are better and more efficient ways. Call it like `GetDayCount(strtotime('2014-10-01'),strtotime('2014-12-06'),"Saturday")`

**UNTESTED**

```
function GetDayCount ($firstdate, $lastdate, $daytype) {

    $ret = 0;
    $date = $firstdate;

    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($lastdate)) {
        if (date('l', $date)=$daytype) {$ret++;}
        $date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    }

        return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Week day parameter should be number (1 = Monday ... 7=Sunday). The bounding dates excluded from count, for including, put `<= and >=` in ternary operators.

```
function weekDayBetweenDates ($dateStart, $dateEnd, $day) {
    $tsStart = strtotime($dateStart);
    $tsEnd = strtotime($dateEnd);
    $diff = floor(strtotime("last monday",$tsEnd) - strtotime("sunday",$tsStart)/(60*60*24*7));
    $diff += date('N', $tsStart)<$day?1:0;
    $diff += date('N', $tsEnd)>$day?1:0;
    return $diff;
}
```